# Written text in Symfony/Twig isn't recognized and thus invisible on my page, how can I fix this issue?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've created a Symfony project, a router, the base template and added a font from Google Fonts in the page but now I've come to the issue that the text I've written inside the page is suddenly disappeared and now invisible in Symfony.

I've checked the DevTools of Firefox (The browser which I use) and it's isn't visible there either.

It was firstly visible before I included a stylesheet and added a custom font from Google Fonts but now it all disappeared. The stylesheet is loaded as usual and the path to it is also correct.

I've then tried to switch to localhost:8000 instead of 127.0.0.1:8000 and back some times without success.

The last things I tried was to clear the cache multiple times and recreate the entire Symfony project from scratch but all things I tried didn't help sadly to fix my issue.

I use the Symfony local webserver as my localhost.

Update: Alright, I asked the same question also on r/Webdev and someone told me there to make a php file called index.php with the text "Hello World" inside it so I made another new page in Twig called Index and then after I have read @Darkbee's comment I removed the body block in the base template in Index and hello world was gone, then I added the body block again and boom: it reappeared. Then I lastly added body block inside the base template of DiCabrio and the text fortunately showed up again so this means my problem is now solved and I can finally move on with my exercise to prepare for the Symfony test on Thursday. I actually removed the body block inside the base template of DiCabrio because I thought I didn't need it but then everything was gone so I want to warn everyone using Symfony: Don't remove the body block inside the base templates!! Or else you all are going to experience what I did. This was a valuable lesson for me and I want to thank everyone for their help, time and effort.

[This is what I see now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4u4C.jpg)

Code:

Template

```
{% extends "DiCabrio_Base.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}
    <h1>Awesome cabrio's:</h1>
    <p>Here are 5 very awesome cabrios to consider!:</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Stylesheet

```
html {
    font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif; 
}
```

Base template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}DiCabrio{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg       xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 128 128%22><text y=%221.2em%22 font-size=%2296%22>⚫️</text></svg>">

        {% block stylesheets %}
            <link rel= "stylesheet" href= "{{ asset ('/CSS      Documents/DiCabrio_Style.css') }}">
        {% endblock %}

        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}

        {% endblock %}
 </head>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

    class DiCabrio_Controller extends AbstractController {

    #[Route ('/' , name: 'DiCabrio')]
    public function dicabrio(): Response {
        return $this->render('DiCabrio.html.twig');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add your code directly to the question. Are you sure  you have defined the block `body` inside `DiCabrio_Base.html.twig`? Please post this template as well

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Let's see your Controller code for this

Comment: Hi @DarkBee, I posted the code of DiCabrio_Base.html.twig as well. I apologize for any of the mistakes, I don't post on StackOverflow very much so bear with me please.

Comment: Hi IanMCL, I've added the controller code and I've changed the text so all code is indented correctly according to the StackOverflow standards and it should be okay now.

Comment: Please enable the debug mode so you can actually see errors appearing, I'm pretty sure this syntax is invalid `{{ asset ('/CSS      Documents/DiCabrio_Style.css') }}`, hence the extra spaces

Comment: Your twig body block is inside the <head> of the html doc. The html doc has no <body>

Comment: @DarkBee, Since your comment contributed to the fix of my issue can you change your comment into an answer so I can mark it as solved and as the answer to my question please?